# Typescript - type safe deep omit, or: how to list legal object paths

Tags: typescript, recursion, recursive-datastructures, typescript-generics

Alright, this is a long and very specific one. Would greatly appreciate any input.

I've written a recursive `Omit` type, which takes a type `T` and a tuple of strings (a 'path'), and indexes into `T`, removing the last item on the path and returning that type.

I've already looked at [Deep Omit With Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539387/deep-omit-with-typescript) - but that deals with recursively omitting the same key rather than traversing along a path.

I've also looked at [Type Safe Omit Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966509/typescript-type-safe-omit-function) but that deals with run-time and is about a one-level omit.

My implementation:

```js
// for going along the tuple that is the path
type Tail<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => void) extends ((head: unknown, ...rest: infer U) => void) ? U : never;

type DeepOmit<T, Path extends string[]> = T extends object ? {
    0: Omit<T, Path[0]>;
    1: { [K in keyof T]: K extends Path[0] ? DeepOmit<T[K], Tail<Path>> : T[K] }
}[Path['length'] extends 1 ? 0 : 1] : T;
```

I want to make it so `Path` is constrained to be a valid traversal of `T`, something like:

```
Path = [K1, K2, K3, ..., K_n] such that:
K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1], ... Kn extends keyof[T][K1]...[K_(n-1)]
```

**First attempt**

I've written a type that takes a type `T` and a path `P` and returns `P` if it's valid, or `never` otherwise:

```js
type ExistingPathInObject<T, P extends any[]> = P extends [] ? P : {
    0: ExistingPathInObject<T[P[0]], Tail<P>> extends never ? never : P;
    1: never;
}[P[0] extends keyof T ? 0 : 1]
```

However, in `DeepOmit`'s signature I can't enforce `Path extends ExistingPathInObject<T,Path>` as that is a circular dependency. I mention this attempt because there might be a way to circumvent the circularity and use this type to verify `Path` as a valid traversal of `T`.

**Second Attempt**

Because I can't seem to use `Path` to constrain itself, I instead tried to generate a union of all existing paths in a type and then require `Path` to extend that. The best I could come up with is this:

```js
type Paths<T> = {
    0: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? [K, Paths<T[K]>[keyof Paths<T[K]>]] : [K] }
    1: []
}[T extends object ? 0 : 1];

// an example type to test on
type HasNested = { a: string; b: { c: number; d: string } };

type pathTest = Paths<HasNested>;
//{
//  a: ["a"];
//  b: ["b", ["d"] | ["c"]];
//}

type pathTestUnion = Paths<HasNested>[keyof Paths<HasNested>]
// ["a"] | ["b", ["d"] | ["c"]]
```

This lets me match a path written as a tree: `['a'] extends pathTestUnion`, and `['b', ['d']] extends pathTestUnion` are both true. I have to add a `[keyof T]` to get the union and I can't put it in the type `Paths` itself because it's not recognized as valid.

Having done all of that, I'm now having difficulty rewriting `DeepOmit` to use this constraint. Here's what I've tried:

```js
type Types<T> = T[keyof T];

type TypeSafeDeepOmit<T, Path extends Types<Paths<T>>, K extends keyof T> =
    Path extends any[] ?
    T extends object ?
    { // T is object and Path is any[]
        0: Omit<T, K>;
        1: { [P in keyof T]: P extends Path[0] ? TypeSafeDeepOmit<T[P], Path[1], Path[1][0]> : T[P] }
    }[Path['length'] extends 1 ? 0 : 1] :
    T : // if T is not object
    never; // if Path is not any[]

type TSDO_Helper<T, P extends Types<Paths<T>>> = P extends any[] ? P[0] extends keyof T ? TypeSafeDeepOmit<T, P, P[0]> : never : never;
```

This is ugly and uses a helper type to actually work. I also have to tell the compiler that `P extends any[]` and `P[0] extends keyof T`, even though that is exactly what `Paths` is meant to ensure. I'm also getting an error in the recursive call of `TypeSafeDeepOmit` using `Path[1]` -

```
Type 'any[] & Path' is not assignable to type '[]'.
        Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'
```

I've fixed that by setting `Path extends Types<Paths<T>> | []` but I'm not sure that's the right way to go about it.

**In summary**

So, is there any nicer way to enforce a valid path? Is it possible to also support a union of paths, so as to omit all of them? Right now the result I get is a union of the results of different omits.

Comment: heh, this is a mess .  Usually in cases like this I just pick a maximum depth (4 or 5 levels) and unroll my "recursive" types to this depth and then bail out. Right now there's no [supported method](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) for such recursive types.   As it stands the official word is [not to do what you're doing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254) with `type R<T> = { 0: X, 1: F<R<T>> }[T extends Y ? 0 : 1]`.  I don't know that I could come up with anything less ugly than what you have.

Comment: 24 hours from discovering that recursion 'hack' to finding out it's not recommended. Oh well, at least it was an interesting experiment! Thanks for the links and your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but I don't know if it counts as an answer.

Here's a really yucky transformation (with many possible edge cases) from a union-of-omits to the multi-omit:

```
type NestedId<T, Z extends keyof any = keyof T> = (
  [T] extends [object] ? { [K in Z]: K extends keyof T ? NestedId<T[K]> : never } : T
) extends infer P ? { [K in keyof P]: P[K] } : never;

type MultiDeepOmit<T, P extends string[]> = NestedId<P extends any ? DeepOmit<T, P> : never>
```

The way it works (if it does work) is to take a union like `{a: string, b: number} | {b: number, c: boolean}` and only use the keys that exist in all of the constituents of the union: `{b: number}`.  It's hard to get that to happen, and breaks optional properties and who knows what else.

Good luck, sorry for no great answer yet.

Comment: This is interesting, I'll need to go over the different parts and see that I understand them. It looks like at the end you're inferring `P` only to reconstruct it, I figure there's more to it than that.

Note that in this version the path is a string tuple rather than the nested paths that I was able to generate.

Comment: Well you can change the constraint on `P` in `MultiDeepOmit` without affecting how it works.  In `NestedId` the infer-and-reconstruct truck prompts the compiler to output a concrete object type if possible instead of a bunch of type aliases.

Comment: I've replaced `NestedId` to end with `extends infer P ? P ...` and didn't see a different results on the few basic types I created to play with. Can you explain what the type aliases otherwise generated would look like? Unfortunately I can't test this for a while now.

Comment: If you're going to do that you might as well just replace `(XXX) extends infer P ? P : never` with `XXX`.  That's fine, too.  It really seems to depend on the environment I'm using whether IntelliSense shows something like `{a: NestedId<{c: string}>, b: NestedId<{d: number}>}` or `{a: {c: string}, b: {d: number}}`.  The `(XXX) extends infer P ? {[K in keyof P]: P[K]} : never`-map trick usually forces the latter in all cases for me, but if it isn't necessary in your environment I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yeah, obviously there's no need to infer P if I'm not manipulating it, it was just a test to see what those aliases would look like as opposed to the concrete type. I think I've run across this problem (like seeing `Pick<{...},'c'>` instead of the resulting type), so this is a useful trick to know!