# Conditional Mapped Return Type Not Working without @ts-ignore

Tags: typescript, type-inference, mapped-types, conditional-types

Building on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966509/typescript-type-safe-omit-function), I wanted to write an `omit` function that was type-safe and accepted either `T` or `T[]` (yeah, I know I can just map over an array and run each item through `omit`, but it's the thing of it!). I can get the whole thing to work, and the type inference is working correctly for the return types, however it won't compile without `@ts-ignore` even though it seems to me that my return types are adequately satisfying the type constraints. This kind of conditional return type seems to work fine for simpler use-cases. Can anyone explain why its not working here and/or how to fix it?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCC2BLKBJeAHANgU3tsUAhlIuDALwwA8AKgJ7rYzYAeU+AJhHAEYBW2YFAA0MANLY6zNp24BrSSABmMeowB8ACgBQMGMlwAuVQ2zDdMAHTWFdCMYl0A2gF1tASmMBvC07H6wGABRFmBMAFcObCpbZRNGUUd1F2M1bD8XAG5tAF8KdRgfPVBIWAAnbFhKLzzCbjTsixxYW2NYlQbtCyUQMphNWwD9dnh3Qos9RBVNAEJbCEtEMDDI7AgByRg68Ul3MaK9Q4qoJ1sXCmHcU8ksiZgciweLY-CywOPsnMaS6DgkKuoFho0nYYC4vAEQnMegAqiDZKoYAAfVSuaE7KSsUHguFYhE0VwwAD8MHaMBhTjA4XgPGwZXObUUKhh5i0FgM8AA8mUUCN7OT0dZLPMHJJXB5jLiZGD6uK9CSDocYH4hiEVlEYkzyZTqbT6YlJMlJTqaXSXBlskqcnKYN47noVUtgqEIhqySyMUbtWJblb8uNJtMAIJlMqEOiLCAhsN0TQc7m83AQPYBw4-cqVC7xnl8yzwQjoTRxsbkAoIZBoLC4fBEEjgOOiIXzPaWpV6AD07ZgAD0iXc7p2YAABKAQAC0iAA5mBetg7i83jAPo8usVwL9jhdy6gMDg8ARiKQwHGRgm+Vt6o2bJJk62253e6uYIOR+OpzOKs9Kq93pVPt911gFgt3+TQvC2YwAEZRB4YwACZRGAYwACJkPuURkMIZCMJ4ZD3DvZ920fbR0xgKRKG3TQnHAwgoJg+DEJQtCchcDCsJwvCCIfPttCAA)

```js
const omitImplementation = <Type extends object, Key extends keyof Type>(
  item: Type,
  ...keys: Key[]
): {
  [K in Exclude<keyof Type, Key>]: Type[K];
} => {
  const ret = {} as Type;

  let key: keyof Type;

  for (key in item) {
    if (!keys.includes(key as Key)) {
      ret[key] = item[key];
    }
  }

  return ret;
};

const omit = <
  T extends object,
  U extends T | T[],
  Key extends U extends T[] ? keyof U[number] : keyof U,
>(
  itemOrItems: U,
  ...keys: Key[]
): U extends T[]
  ? {
      [K in Exclude<keyof U[number], Key>]: U[number][K];
    }[]
  : {
      [K in Exclude<keyof U, Key>]: U[K];
    } => {
  if (Array.isArray(itemOrItems)) {
    const ret = itemOrItems.map((i) => omitImplementation(i, ...keys));
    
    // @ts-ignore
    return ret; // <- error!
  }

  const ret = omitImplementation(itemOrItems as T, ...keys);

  // @ts-ignore
  return ret; // <- error!
};

const x = omit({ a: 1, b: 2, c: "" }, "a", "b");
// correctly infers as { c: string }

const y = omit([{ a: 1, b: 2, c: "" }], "a", "b");
// correctly infers as { c: string }[]
```

Comment: [I think overloads are simpler.](https://tsplay.dev/w61ArW)

Comment: @caTS interesting point. I'll give it a shot - better to avoid the ts-ignore if I can. Though I'd still like to know what's wrong with this...

Comment: @caTS right you are: [repl](https://replit.com/@no_stack_dub_sack/TypeScript#index.ts). I sometimes forget to reach for overloads, or fail to recognize when they'd benefit me. Thanks for the reminder.